# XStream: convert collection with attributes

Tags: xstream

The XML I'm trying to convert looks like:

```
<numberOfEmployees year="2013">499.0</numberOfEmployees>
```

According to the XSD, there can be multiple of these tags, so it's a collection. The generated code looks like:

```
    protected List<NumberOfPersonnel> numberOfEmployees;
```

When I use `@XStreamImplicit`, it drops the value, so I need a converter. But combining `@XStreamImplicit` with `@XStreamConverter` doesn't seem to work.

So how do I do this? I've tried messing about with my own custom converter that inherits from CollectionConverter, but it claims not to find any children, and honestly I have no idea what I'm doing.

Could someone enlighten me? This shouldn't be this hard, should it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can make it work by using [`ToAttributedValueConverter`](http://xstream.codehaus.org/annotations-tutorial.html#FieldAsText) on the `NumberOfPersonnel` class and `@XStreamImplicit` on the List-valued property:

**NumberOfPersonnel.java**

```java
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.*;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.ToAttributedValueConverter;

// treat the "value" property as the element content and all others as attributes
@XStreamConverter(value = ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings = {"value"})
public class NumberOfPersonnel {
  public NumberOfPersonnel(int year, double value) {
    this.year = year;
    this.value = value;
  }

  private int year;

  private double value;

  public String toString() {
    return year + ": " + value;
  }
}
```

**Container.java**

```java
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.File;

@XStreamAlias("container")
public class Container {
  private String name;

  // any element named numberOfEmployees should go into this list
  @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="numberOfEmployees")
  protected List<NumberOfPersonnel> numberOfEmployees;

  public Container(String name, List<NumberOfPersonnel> noEmp) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numberOfEmployees = noEmp;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return name + ", " + numberOfEmployees;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    XStream xs = new XStream();
    xs.processAnnotations(Container.class);

    System.out.println("Unmarshalling:");
    System.out.println(xs.fromXML(new File("in.xml")));

    System.out.println("Marshalling:");
    System.out.println(xs.toXML(new Container("World",
           Arrays.asList(new NumberOfPersonnel(2001, 1000),
                         new NumberOfPersonnel(2002, 500)))));
  }
}
```

**in.xml**

```xml
<container>
  <name>Hello</name>
  <numberOfEmployees year="2013">499.0</numberOfEmployees>
  <numberOfEmployees year="2012">550.0</numberOfEmployees>
</container>
```

**Output**

```
Unmarshalling:
Hello, [2013: 499.0, 2012: 550.0]
Marshalling:
<container>
  <name>World</name>
  <numberOfEmployees year="2001">1000.0</numberOfEmployees>
  <numberOfEmployees year="2002">500.0</numberOfEmployees>
</container>
```

Comment: Thanks you! This does exactly what I need in a much more elegant way than I was trying to do. It also looks like all the custom converters a co-worker wrote are unnecessary and should be replaced with this one.