# Xstream: JAVA to XML

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I want to create an JAVA object, that could be converted into XML structure

```
<a id="[numeric value]">[string value]</a>
```

I read the tutorials on Xstream site and googled some time, but I can't find solutions.

For example, to convert the POJO to

```
<many_a>
    <a id="[numeric value]">
         <name>[string value]</name>
    </a>
    ...
</many_a>
```

I will create POJOs

```
@XStreamAlias("many_a")
class AList{
    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "a")
    List<A> list;
}
class A{
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    @XStreamAlias("id")
    long id;
    @XStreamAlias("name")
    String name;
}
```

So, the question is which POJO I should create to get the XML above?

Comment: you can use Map<Integer,String> to marshal your object

Comment: so, the only solution is a custom converter?

Comment: Have a look at http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/collections/MapConverter.html too

Comment: I feel like I dont quite understand the question, but this is the easiest API ive used for serializing to XML with a POJO type object, if using something other than XStream is an option: http://simple.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map<Integer,String>` to marshal your object , if you have all entries in your xml as you specified.
Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098261/converting-xml-to-java-mapstring-integer-with-xstream) question to get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution how to solve this issue without writing your custom converter.
See this thread:

[XStream: convert collection with attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616142/xstream-convert-collection-with-attributes)